# XCode creating half-sized static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

This issue is driving me nuts. I am asking it here before I announce it as a bug in XCode and try to use another version of XCode.

So, I am using XCode 8.3.2. I have a project that generates a static library. I am moving the .a file to another project and I use it (I know I can integrate the static library project in the second project but I don't want that here).

The file generated is 4.4MB. After copying the newly created .a and I copy it to the second project and test it, everything works fine. But when I come back to the library project and build it, the generated file is 2.3MB with missing symbols!!!

I cannot make it work unless I restart my MAC, or XCode somehow crashes.

What I have tried : Clean project, clean folder, delete Derived data, added -all_load -force_load -ObjC flags in my target linker flags.

If anyone has any idea about what is happening, please inform me.
Thanks!

Comment: May be second time, you have removed one slice from fat library, while building.

Comment: I did not quite understand what you said. But I did nothing between the 2 builds other than copying the library to another location. I think it's a XCode cache problem.

Comment: What was the device type during first and second operation?

Comment: Sometimes on the build only device, the others iphone 6S and iphone 5S.

Comment: Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends upon the target device you have selected during building your library. In Xcode, When you select any specific simulator or device, that time Xcode only creates single slice or thin product. 
[image]
[image]
If you select Generic iOS device , means no device or simulator, that time Xcode create library having all the device slices and one folder having Simulator slice.

By using LIPO command you can put simulator and device slices together.

In your case, during first and second time, You are changing the device target from Generic iOS Device to specific device.

Comment: It's the static functionality in xcode, when I choose my iPhone in the second project to run it, XCode changes it also in the library project.